# "Private" jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've scoured the internet for an answer to this, to no avail.  I feel like the answer is probably very simple, but it's been eluding me.

I'm writing a jQuery plugin, and following all the best practices.  Let's say my plugin is called foo, and I have the following standard plugin definition:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.foo = function() {
    this.append('<p>I'm doing stuff!</p>');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Pretty basic so far.  Now let's say I have some **internal** functionality that I want to encapsulate in a function called bar.  Here's the catch, though: I want to call it like a jQuery plugin so I can take advantage of chaining, etc.  That is, I want to be able to use it like this:

```
(function($){
  /* this is bad: it clutters up the namespace, and exposes implementation details:
  $.fn.bar = function(text) {
    this.append('<p>'+text'</p>');
  }
  */
  $.fn.foo = function() {
    this.append('<p>I'm doing stuff!</p>').bar('bar does something else!');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

How can I declare bar so that I can call it like a jQuery plugin, but it is not available outside of the scope of my plugin?

I messed around with using Javascript's apply method, and I got something that sort of worked, but it was clunky, and no better than just calling the function with a jQuery object as a parameter.

I'm sure there's a simple solution...anybody?

Comment: You can use Closure to wrap your private method. i.e making your plugin on a modular design.

Answer (score 1):

Ethan, using the plugin pattern advocated [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), a range of possibilities exists, including private functions and a range of public methods all within the one plugin.

You can have private functions and they could conceivably be chainable (of sorts), but :

- you generally can't chain internally because internal calls tend to be made with `.call()`.
- you generally don't want or need chainability internally because public methods are typically of the form `return this.each(function(){...});`, and within this loop the code addresses a single element of the jQuery selection on which it is acting.

For example :

```
(function($){
    // **********************************
    // ***** Start: Private Members *****
    var pluginName = 'foo';
    var cough = function(text, bgColor) {
        text = text || ''; 
        bgColor = bgColor || '#FFF';
        $(this).append($('<p/>').append(text).css('backgroundColor', bgColor));
    };
    // ***** Fin: Private Members *****
    // ********************************

    // *********************************
    // ***** Start: Public Methods *****
    var methods = {
        init: function(text) {
            text = text || 'foo init!';
            return this.each(function() {
                methods.bar.call($(this), 'cough from bar from init');
                cough.call($(this), 'cough from init');
            });
        },
        bar: function(text) {
            text = text || 'cough from bar!';
            return this.each(function() {
                cough.call(this, text, '#99CC99');
            });
        }
    };
    // ***** Fin: Public Methods *****
    // *******************************

    // *****************************
    // ***** Start: Supervisor *****
    $.fn[pluginName] = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' + method + ' does not exist in jQuery.' + pluginName );
        }
    };
    // ***** Fin: Supervisor *****
    // ***************************
})(jQuery);
```

Here the plugin 'foo' has a has public methods 'init' and 'bar', and a private utility 'cough', which is called internally by both `init` and 'bar'.

You can call

```
$("div").foo(); //same as $("div").foo(init');
$("div").foo('bar', 'cough from bar');
```

But `cough` isn't available to be called externally.

Note: In the pattern above, the supervisor is always exactly the same - it doesn't need to be edited.